# Razor show / hide base on radio button using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

I am trying to hide or show a textbox, in a ASP MVC razor view, now i using javascript to handle when i click the radio button which can help me to do  hide or show function.
however, i want to base on database record hide and show the textbox, so if i use below code , i need to click the radio for hide or show a textbox, anyone can give me advise how to hide or show textbox base on database record and no need to click radio button? thanks

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        const { checked } = require("modernizr");

         function text(x) {

           if  (x == 0 ) document.getElementById("name").style.display = "block",
                document.getElementById("address").style.display = "none",
               
            else  document.getElementById("name").style.display = "none",
                document.getElementById("address").style.display = "block",
            return;

        }

    </script>
```

```html
   //radio name
   @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Type, "A")
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.Type, "A" , new { @onclick = "text(0)", @id = "but1" })
   
   @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Type, "B")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.Type, "B" , new { @onclick = "text(1)", @id = "but2" })

//textbox(name)
 <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="name">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name, new { @class = "control-label" })
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.name, new { @class = "form-control"e })
 </div>
 //textbox(address)
  <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="address">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.address, new { @class = "control-label" })
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.address, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by no need to click radio button? @iamnew

Comment: Personally I use javascript to copy the current input value into an attribute of a parent html tag. Then static css rules can locate the items to show / hide.

Comment: @SanjitMajumdar Yes, when i entry the page  the radio button will be default A or B base on database, but now i need to click the radio button for show or hide column, cannot automate from default A or B type. thanks

Comment: Hi,@JeremyLakeman , yes it is working but if default B type the name textbox will hide , but if i default A type, the name textbox also hide,(A type should be show name textbox).thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
  // self executing function here
(function() {
  // your page initialization code here
  // the DOM will be available here
  text(@Model.Value);
})();
</script>
```

This is a document ready function. Your text() method will be called when page is loaded.
Use @Model.Value your initial db value. That way it will work for the first time with the value which is in the db.